# Retrofit Sending Json

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to send a Json to a payment gateway through Retrofit. I really do not know what I have badly tested postman and everything works well. when trying to adapt with retrofit I only get null as a response.

My class Utils

```
 public class ApiUtils {
        private ApiUtils() {}

 public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.payulatam.com/";

        public static APIService getAPIService() {

            return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
        }
    }
```

My interface Class

```
public interface APIService {

    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("payments-api/4.0/service.cgi/")
    Call<Ping> sendPing(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);

}
```

My POJO of the server response.

```
public class Ping {

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;
    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private Object error;
    @SerializedName("transactionResponse")
    @Expose
    private Object transactionResponse;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Object getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Object error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public Object getTransactionResponse() {
        return transactionResponse;
    }

    public void setTransactionResponse(Object transactionResponse) {
        this.transactionResponse = transactionResponse;
    }

}
```

Main Activities, Ping is the method where I send the Json with the requirements requested by the gateway. I always get an answer null

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private JsonObject SendObj;
    private JsonObject objPing;
    private TextView mResponseTv;
    private APIService mAPIService;
    private String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Ping();
            }
        });
    }

    private void Ping(){
        JsonObject objMerchant = new JsonObject();
        objMerchant.addProperty("apiLogin", "XXXXXXXXXXX");
        objMerchant.addProperty("apiKey","XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        JsonObject objPing = new JsonObject();
        objPing.addProperty("test", "false");
        objPing.addProperty("language","es");
        objPing.addProperty("command","PING");
        objPing.add("merchant",objMerchant);
        SendPing(objPing);
        Log.i(TAG, "Obj" + objPing.toString());

    }


    public void SendPing(JsonObject body) {
        Call <Ping> call = mAPIService.sendPing(body);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Ping>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Ping> call, Response<Ping> response) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Getting response from server : "+ response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Ping> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Getting response from server failure: "+ t);
            }
        });
    }




}
```

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N77P.png)

Comment: can you show your postman? the post request and response result

Answer (score 0):

Why there's no endpoint in @POST("./")?

Basically BASE_URL should be **https://api.payulatam.com/** and your POST endpoint should be

`@POST("payments-api/4.0/service.cgi/")`

Besides, why are you creating request body manually? You can use a POJO class to serialize the request and I think it will be easier to handle that way. 
For example,

`public class Request{
@SerializedName("language")
public String language; //you can use private as well
}`

and to create the request,

`Request request = new Request();
request.language = "es";`

So in your interface, put it this way:

`Call<Ping> sendPing(@Body Request request);`

Can you try this and see?

Updated request object from postman request:

```
public class Request {@SerializedName("test")
    public boolean test;

    @SerializedName("language")
    public String language;

    @SerializedName("command")
    public String command;

    @SerializedName("merchant")
    public Merchant merchant;

    public class Merchant{
        @SerializedName("apiLogin")
        public String apiLogin;

        @SerializedName("apiKey")
        public String apiKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. try your way I still get the same answer null

Comment: Can you share the RetrofitClient code? Or can u add HttpLoggingInterceptor so you can trace the request and response more easily.

HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            builder.addInterceptor(interceptor);

Comment: Hi Vision, i've updated my answer based on your postman request. You can try to use the request object provided.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mention that:

```
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
})
```

So remove this from your code.

test is boolean in your postman request but here you are passing as string so change following:

```
 JsonObject objMerchant = new JsonObject();
    objMerchant.addProperty("apiLogin", "XXXXXXXXXXX");
    objMerchant.addProperty("apiKey","XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    JsonObject objPing = new JsonObject();
    objPing.addProperty("test", "false");
    objPing.addProperty("language","es");
    objPing.addProperty("command","PING");
    objPing.add("merchant",objMerchant);
```

to:

```
 JsonObject objMerchant = new JsonObject();
    objMerchant.addProperty("apiLogin", "XXXXXXXXXXX");
    objMerchant.addProperty("apiKey","XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    JsonObject objPing = new JsonObject();
    objPing.addProperty("test", false);
    objPing.addProperty("language","es");
    objPing.addProperty("command","PING");
    objPing.add("merchant",objMerchant);
```

Test attribute is boolean in your postman request but here you were passing as string.

Comment: Also share the body of send request from postman where it gives you success response. I want to check if you are making json correctly or not.

Comment: hi, update my publication at the end is the link of my postman.

Comment: Buddy I updated answer implement suggested changes this will work. good luck !

Comment: I get the same answer Getting response from server: null. Perform a test with postman sent as String "false" and works equally with postman, with retrofit seems to be my problem.